# Unity Android Build Issue - IL2CPP error (No further information)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, build, il2cpp

I've been trying to make a build for Android with Unity, and I keep getting this error. I've reinstalled the Unity version and a few SDKs, but I can't figure anything out unfortunately. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Error: IL2CPP error (no further information about what managed code was being converted is available)
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Found a method reference we cannot resolve to a method definition: UnityEngine.Touch[] UnityEngine.Input::get_touches())
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Found a method reference we cannot resolve to a method definition: UnityEngine.Touch[] UnityEngine.Input::get_touches()
    at Unity.IL2CPP.DataModel.BuildLogic.MethodReferenceResolver.ResolveMethodReference(TypeContext context, UnderConstructionMethodReferenceRepository repository, CecilSourcedAssemblyData assemblyData, MethodReference methodReference, Dictionary`2 mapping)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.DataModel.BuildLogic.MethodReferenceResolver.ResolveAssemblyMethodReferences(TypeContext context, UnderConstructionMethodReferenceRepository repository, CecilSourcedAssemblyData assemblyDef, ReadOnlyHashSet`1 methodReferences)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.DataModel.BuildLogic.DataModelBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<ResolveReferences>b__0(CecilSourcedAssemblyData data)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass33_0`2.<ForEachWorker>b__0(Int32 i)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1(RangeWorker& currentWorker, Int32 timeout, Boolean& replicationDelegateYieldedBeforeCompletion)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1(RangeWorker& currentWorker, Int32 timeout, Boolean& replicationDelegateYieldedBeforeCompletion)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskReplicator.Replica`1.ExecuteAction(Boolean& yieldedBeforeCompletion)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskReplicator.Replica.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskReplicator.Run[TState](ReplicatableUserAction`1 action, ParallelOptions options, Boolean stopOnFirstFailure)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ThrowSingleCancellationExceptionOrOtherException(ICollection exceptions, CancellationToken cancelToken, Exception otherException)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IList`1 list, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 body)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.DataModel.BuildLogic.Utils.ParallelHelpers.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 func, Boolean enableSerial)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.DataModel.BuildLogic.DataModelBuilder.Build()
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Contexts.Components.DataModelComponent.Load(LoadSettings loadSettings, Boolean ownsTypeContext, Boolean ownsBuilder, DataModelBuilder& builder)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConversion.Phases.InitializePhase.Run(AssemblyConversionContext context)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConversion.Classic.ClassicConverter.Run(AssemblyConversionContext context)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConversion.AssemblyConverter.ConvertAssemblies(AssemblyConversionInputData data, AssemblyConversionParameters parameters, AssemblyConversionInputDataForTopLevelAccess dataForTopLevel)
```